# Laravel print logs

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to print logs on console :

I imported :

```
use Log;
```

and then used in controller

```
 Log::info('test log');
```

but its not printing any logs.

Comment: try \Log::info('test log'); also check file permission.

Comment: I misread the question you should use `use dump(), dd(), or print_r()` To see in concole.

Comment: Where are you looking to see the logs? By default, they're in `storage/logs/laravel.log`. They won't be in your webserver logs or the console.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need to check `storage/logs/laravel.log` after run

```
Log::info('test log');
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You've to config where laravel to store the logs. Default `Log::info()` put the log in the log file not the console. you can use tail -f logpath to see the log.

Comment: Thanks! I am totally new to laravel so didn't knew it.

Answer (score 1):

Under normal circumstances, log issues are associated with **proper write permissions** to the log folder(storage/logs).

If you are using debugging/reporting libraries like **Bugsnag,** you need to explicitly specify that you need Laravel logs and Bugsnag logs. To enable Laravel logs along with Bugsnag, register Bugsnag in the AppServiceProvider with the `multi` option.

```
public function register() {
    // Bugsnag
    $this->app->alias('bugsnag.multi', \Illuminate\Contracts\Logging\Log::class);
    $this->app->alias('bugsnag.multi', \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface::class);
}
```